# camera.getPicture() always get to failed for Phonegap 2.9.0

Tags: cordova

I'm using the below code,

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(failed, completed, { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });

function completed() {
    alert('got it');
}

function failed() {
    alert('Failed to get the photo');
}
```

It always get to the fail function. Am i missing any permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the error callback to success and success callback to error.

You are getting the correct callback but its calling the failed as you provided,

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(completed, failed, { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });
```